# T-SQL count number of fields associated with a GUID and get sum of fields from another table associated with the same GUIDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

EDIT:
Hey Everyone,

I figured it out

```
select LI.ProjectId, count(*) as numLineItems
into #temp
from dbo.SQLLineItems as LI
group by LI.ProjectId
having COUNT(*) < =200

select numLineItems, count(*), SUM(PT.GrandTotalSell) from
#temp
inner join dbo.SQLProjectTotals as PT
on PT.ProjectId = #temp.ProjectId
group by numLineItems;
```

Thank you for your help.

---

I have two tables that contain project information. Table 1 contains LineItems each with a GUID that is unique to that table and GUID for ProjectID. There are duplicates of each ProjectID since there can be multiple LineItems for one ProjectID.

Table 2 is linked to Table 1 by Project ID and the GUID is unique in that table. Table 2 also contains the price of each project.

I wanted to breakdown the projects by number of LineItems to see how many projects are 1, 2, 3, 4... item projects.

I wrote a query that works:

```
use FieldedProjects;

select LI.ProjectId, count(*) as numLineItems
into #temp
from dbo.SQLLineItems as LI
group by LI.ProjectId
having COUNT(*) < =15

select numLineItems, count(*) from
#temp
group by numLineItems;
```

but now I want to modify it to show the price totals. So the total project prices for 1 item projects is 100, 2 item projects is 300,...

I was thinking something like

```
use FieldedProjects;

select LI.ProjectId, count(*) as numLineItems, SUM(PT.GrandTotalSell) as projectTotal
into #temp
from dbo.SQLLineItems as LI
inner join dbo.SQLProjectTotals as PT
on LI.ProjectID = PT.ProjectID
group by LI.ProjectId
having COUNT(*) < =15

select numLineItems, count(*), projectTotal from
#temp
group by numLineItems;
```

But it gives me an error because projectTotal is not contained in an aggregate function. Is it supposed to be

```
select numLineItems, count(*), SUM(projectTotal) from
```

Comment: `group by numLineItems, projectTotal` -- will it work?

Comment: lets say you have three 2-item projects, with 10, 20, 30 as projectTotals. In your result you want to see a row with 2 as a [2-item], 3 as countOf2ItemProjects, and ??? do you want those projectTotals to be summed again or string representation of comma delimited numbers?

Comment: I want one sum for the project totals and a column next to it that is the sum of the GrandTotalSell for each project that was counted. So what is the number of n item projects and what is the sum of the GrandTotalSells for all n item projects? I will try Roman's answer and see what comes of that. It may also be as simple as
    group by numLineItems, projectTotal

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from dbo.SQLProjectTotals as PT
cross apply
(
    select count(*)
    from dbo.SQLLineItems LI
    where LI.ProjectID = PT.ProjectID
) items(Count)
where items.Count <= 15
```